# Calculating Chronic Daily Intake

Tags: environmental-engineering

I am studying for the FE exam and have come across a question regarding calculating cancer risk.  I'm fairly certain that the answer provided has typos, but I'm not 100% sure.  Here is the question:

A carcinogen is in drinking water at a concentration of 0.01 mg/L.  The cancer risk of 30 years of adult (75 kg) exposure, given a cancer slope factor of 0.80 [mg/(kg*day)]^-1, is most nearly:

I understand that the chronic daily intake equation is CDI = [(Concentration)(Ingestion Rate)(Exposure Frequency)(Exposure Duration)]/[(Body Weight)(Averaging Time)]

Here are my issues with solution provided:

1. The ingestion rate is 2.3 L/day.  That wasn't given in the question, and the standard ingestion rate anyways given by the EPA is 2 L/day.  How did they come up with this number?  Is it likely just a typo?
2. For "Averaging Time", they have multiplied 75*365...shouldn't it be 30*365 since the question states that it is 30 years of exposure??

Comment: For the Medical Sciences Stack?

Comment: Not sure, since this is an environmental engineering topic I figured I'd put it in the engineering stack.

Comment: I just took FE this year, chemical. If I remember right, I think averaging time for CDI is lifespan, not years of exposure. Did they give an average lifespan?

Answer (score 1):

The 75 is the exposure duration (ED) in this scenario it is a carcinogen so the lifetime duration is used. [image]

Comment: A reference/citation for the information in the answer should be included.